# Resolve different implementations of interface using Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to resolve a different implementation of an interface for different classes using Autofac, the reason being that I want to send updates to clients via a SignalR hub in my message handler - however I don't want the handler to be a hub client itself and different handlers need to use different hubs.

What I had initially looks like this:

```
public class Hub1 : Hub { }
public class Hub2 : Hub { }

public class Handler1 : IHandle<Message1>
{
    private AppData data;
    private IHubContext hubContext;

    public Handler1(AppData data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hub1>()
    }
}

public class Handler2 : IHandle<Message2>
{
    private AppData data;
    private IHubContext hubContext;

    public Handler2(AppData data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hub2>()
    }
}
```

Which works with Autofac bindings as follows:

```
// Single shared instance of AppData for all handlers
builder.RegisterType<AppData>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<Handler1>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<Handler2>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Both handlers already have `AppData` injected via Autofac, however I would also like to inject the `IHubContext` but I am struggling to figure out how to do it.

I have changed to require the `IHubContext` as a constructor argument in the handlers:

```
public class Handler1 : IHandle<Message1>
{
    private AppData data;
    private IHubContext hubContext;

    public Handler1(AppData data, IHubContext hubContext)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.hubContext = hubContext;
    }
}
```

I have tried registering the `IHubContext` as a named service and specifying the registration for the handlers as follows:

```
builder.Register<IHubContext>(_ => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hub1>())
    .Named<IHubContext>("Hub1Context");

builder.Register<IHubContext>(_ => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hub2>())
    .Named<IHubContext>("Hub2Context");

builder.RegisterType<Handler1>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IHubContext>("Hub1Context"));

builder.RegisterType<Handler2>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IHubContext>("Hub2Context"));
```

However this results in an exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll

Additional information: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Handler1' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:

Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext hubContext' of constructor 'Void .ctor(AppData, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext)'.
```

Where am I going wrong? I've done something similar in the past with Ninject by just saying something along the lines of:

```
kernel.Bind<IHubContext>()
      .ToMethod(_ => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hub1>())
      .WhenInjectedInto<Handler1>();
```

Comment: Looks like you need to make the property public or require IHubContext in constructor.

Comment: @Victor I have made the constructor accept the `IHubContext`, the problem is that Autofac doesn't know how to resolve it (as per the exception)

Comment: Are you setting up the Autofac container before or after mapping the hubs (when SignalR is initialized)? You need to set up the container *before* SignalR.

Comment: @Quackmatic - They are set up at the same time, I have a call to `builder.RegisterHubs(...)` which happens after the registration code above - not sure why it should make a difference though?

Comment: @TrevorPilley: Hey! Did you solve that problem??

Comment: @JoseA I managed to get something to work, but I no longer work on the project that I was struggling with this on so I can't remember exactly what I did

Comment: @TrevorPilley: Thanks :)